# How to add segments using google analytics add on in google sheets

Tags: google-analytics

Using the google analytics add on in google sheets.I  set metrics = ga:users, dimension = ga:sourceMedium. How do I add a segment such as medium = AZC? Any value I place in segment results in an error; invalid parameter for segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whether you want to segment by sessions or users, your segment will look like one of the following strings.

```
sessions::condition::ga:sourceMedium==AZC
users::condition::ga:sourceMedium==AZC
```

This link will take you to Google's documentation on segments...
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/segments